# ReactJS: Call API at app initialization or every time I need it?

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

I'm building a web app - I have some data about movies stored in API, user can search for them by the title, director etc, rate them and do some other basic things.

I'm wondering what is the best approach to deal with data - call it once (f.e in componentWillMount in the main App Component) keep it in Redux store and add a function to listen API for changes or just call it only when I need it? I want to do a 'live' search box, so it will display data on every change in Input. Isn't better then to call it just once at the beggining? Or will it be to large to keep it in store?

Comment: If possible, please post the code that you have tried so that we can better understand your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should never fetch data in componentWillMount, use componentDidMount.

[Where in the component lifecycle should I make an AJAX call?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#where-in-the-component-lifecycle-should-i-make-an-ajax-call)